# Выпуск видеочата №10 с @Дмитрий Полянин и @Anton Menshov 11.11.2020 в 9:39

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, видеочат

Ура! Мы планируем записать очередной выпуск видеочата сообщества в среду 11-го ноября 2020 года в 9:39 по московскому времени. Гостями десятого выпуска будут:

- [@Дмитрий Полянин](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/205037/). Дмитрий закончил Мех-Мат МГУ им М.В. Ломоносова, а затем аспирантуру МГУИЭ, является создателем [Школы разработчика](https://okeanij.ru), автором новаторского метода обучения программированию, преподает в Институте Бизнеса и Дизайна в Москве, автор проекта с открытым исходным кодом [SunEngine](https://github.com/sunengine/SunEngine), а также участник команды разработки VueJs фреймворка [Quasar](https://quasar.dev).  В свободное время любит фотографировать и гулять на природе.
- [@Anton Menshov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/337980/anton-menshov). Антон закончил Московский Институт Электронной Техники по специальности “Информатика и управление” и магистратуру Университета Манитобы (Канада) по вычислительному электромагнетизму. Работает вице-президентом по инженерии в компании CEMWorks в Канаде. Модератор сообщества по вычислительной науке [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). Увлекается геокэшингом, посткроссингом и рассекает на велосипеде пока поздний августовский канадский снег не перекроет выход из дома.

Тема этого выпуска — **«Выбор технологий в сегодняшнем динамичном мире»**.

#### Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы!

Расскажите, что бы вам хотелось узнать о подходах к выбору новых технологий сегодня у участников выпуска? Поскольку одна из главных целей выпуска познакомиться друг с другом, пожалуйста, задавайте вопросы ребятам про их профессиональный опыт и личные проекты. Я буду благодарен за заранее отправленные вопросы на мою почту (nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com). Также вы можете задать ваш вопрос в виде комментария или ответа в данном вопросе.

---

**[Ссылка на трансляцию](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMkWJQwBE8A)**

Comment: Вопрос к Дмитрию. С чего начался проект SunEngine ? Какой путь прошёл от первого commit до первой звезды на github? Какие можете дать советы людям начинающим свои opensource проекты ?

Comment: @MilkyWay Совет - не боятся. Проект начался когда я хотел сделать свою Школу Разработчика как движок для проекта, это было 5 лет назад и тогда он был не OpenSource и написан на AspNet Mvc 5. Потом возникла идея сделать с нуля на новых технологиях OpenSource. На самом деле там длинная история. Могу в чате более подробно рассказать.

Comment: Второй совет. Делать своё, без оглядки на других.

Comment: вопрос, а где это будет проходить?

Comment: @AndreyFreiz Скорее всего, через Zoom с трансляцией на YouTube канал.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а можешь скинуть ссылку на YouTube канал где это будет проводиться или в зуме?

Comment: @AndreyFreiz Конечно! =) https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwwnMkw2Lok36TtjEVd7uqQ

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky благодарю, обязательно приду =)

Comment: Каким было ваше первое собеседование?

Comment: @entithat Это было так давно, наверное около 16 лет назад, уже не помню. Помню только первое успешное. Неуспешные обычно не запоминаются, покрайней мере мне, если там не было каких-то запоминающихся или курьёзных моментов.

Answer (score 7):

1. Влияет ли выбор технологий на успех проекта? Если да, то как. Если нет, то на что он влияет.
2. Оказывает ли влияние на развитие проекта выбор технологий в разрезе СУБД - SQL или NoSQL решение.

Answer (score 6):

Всем огромное спасибо за внимание и вопросы. К сожалению, в отведенное время и в рамках отведенной темы на все ответить было просто невозможно. **В этом посте постараюсь ответить на те, что не вошли в видеочат.**

> Антон, оцените по сложности обучение в Университете Манитобы и МИЭТ.

Будет очень сильно зависеть от специальности и того, что хочется получить от учебы. Кроме того, МИЭТ я закачивал в 2010, уже 10 лет назад, наверняка многое поменялось. По вопросу: мне было довольно легко учиться в МИЭТе, и я работал с первого курса на пол-ставки, а с четвертого — на полную ставку, без особого ущерба для учебы. Приходилось много выкручиваться, вырываться на лабы, приходить вечером, переписывать лекции у товарищей (им — отдельное спасибо, без них я бы недоучился).

В Университете Манитобы цель была уже совсем другая: научное исследование, и курсы выбирались те, которые мне были либо очень интересны, либо нужны. Поэтому учиться было сложно не из-за оценок, а из-за необходимости достигать свои внутренние цели. Тут я повпахивал мама, не горюй. Примерно то же могу сказать и про свой опыт в Университете Техаса в Остине.

> Насколько сложно найти сотрудников в Виннипеге?

Смотря каких. Сложно, но можно. Качественные C++ программисты здесь встречаются, также как и качественные электроинженеры и специалисты по вычислительное науке. Сочетание трех качеств очень редкое, и приходится либо растить уже на рабочем месте, либо искать компромиссные варианты. Стараемся находить, находим, плюс не ограничиваем поиск только Виннипегом, а ищем по всей Канаде и за рубежом, как с опциями переезда, так и без. Гибкость – это очень важно для работодателя в высокотехнологичной среде, и тут у конкретно нашей CEMWorks преимущество в в том, что мы разрабатываем "чисто-конкретно" код. Это облегчает удаленную работу.

> Каким было ваше первое собеседование?

Мое первое собеседование на позицию бакомойщика в детском лагере было простым: "Тут, это, бакомойщики уволились. Не хочешь оставшиеся пару недель помыть баки и заработать?" — "Ну..." — "Посуду дома моешь?" — "Иногда..." — "Вперед". Дело было перед 11 классом школы. Но, я думаю, это вас не очень интересует.

Первое техническое собеседование было на позицию инженера связи. Но оно было достаточно формальным, ибо все знали что меня возьмут, так как приглашали меня по знакомсву. Показали терминал Linux и спросили, что я могу сделать тут.

Второе техническое собеседование было в Parallels на должность оператора тех-поддержки на английском языке. Проводила собеседование HR, задавала много вопросов о том как же я буду совмещать работу и учебу, поспрашивала о технических знаниях и выяснилось, что я об Apple не знаю ничего. Плюс, много техподдержки было по телефону, а я немного заикаюсь (ну иногда и много). Мне отказали (без причины), но, пожалуй, по делу. А на следующий день позвонили и предложили пройти собеседование "на маркетинг". Так я оказался в Parallels на два года менеджером партнерских программ. Замечательный опыт.

> Не считаете ли Вы, что в последнее время проблемой является не отсутствие новых технологий и инструментов, а стремительный рост их количества? Как сориентироваться среди них и не потратить время впустую на их изучение?

Стремительный рост количества технологий и интсрументов — это проблема, но ее приятно решать. Читать профессионалов, общаться в профессиональных кругах, смотреть, что применяют в успешных\популярных"блестящих" проектах — так можно многое решить. Кроме того, важно окружить себя людьми, которые умнее вас; тогда вам будет легче обитать в океане технологий и инструментов.

> Как Вы относитесь к тому, что многие фреймворки/библиотеки/платформы вместо дальнейшего развития стандартов стремятся изобрести свой велосипед, на котором впоследствии нам всем приходиться учиться ездить?

Изобретение своих велосипедов и развитие стандартов — это очень тяжелый вопрос. Иногда стандарты сильно тормозят развитие. Иногда отсутствие стандартов и велосипедный парк не дают возможность развивать продукты и даже целые отрасли эффективно. Перестандартизация — тоже вполне реальная проблема. К этой проблеме я бы подходил case-by-case, то бишь, индивидуально по-разному в каждом конкретном случае.

Answer (score 4):

Имеет ли смысл сразу переходит на новые технологии, или же стоит использовать старые надежные вещи (по принципу "the old is gold")?

Comment: Мнение в разрезе C++03->C++17->C++20 для коммерческого софта или использование docker+разворот в облаке или использование нового фреймворка для ключевого\неключевого модуля софта компании - будет ли это интересно?

Comment: @AntonMenshov Конечно ;)

Answer (score 4):

Не считаете ли Вы, что в последнее время проблемой является не отсутствие новых технологий и инструментов, а стремительный рост их количества? Как сориентироваться среди них и не потратить время впустую на их изучение? Как Вы относитесь к тому, что многие фреймворки/библиотеки/платформы вместо дальнейшего развития стандартов стремятся изобрести свой велосипед, на котором впоследствии нам всем приходиться учиться ездить?

Как Вы можете прокомментировать тот факт, что в последние годы, многие гиганты IT-индустрии диаметрально противоположно сменили свой курс *(или это меняется сейчас на наших глазах)*?
*Имеется ввиду ситуация с лицензированием Java, движение Microsoft в сторону кроссплатформенности и открытости ПО с .Net, прекращение разработки MS своего браузерного движка и переход на WebKit.*

Answer (score 3):

Дмитрий, есть ли общий подход к обучению, чтобы заинтересовать людей или к каждому подходите индивидуально?

Антон, оцените по сложности обучение в Университете Манитобы и МИЭТ.
Насколько сложно найти сотрудников в Виннипеге?

Comment: А что такое винипег ??

Comment: город в Канаде, где базируется CEMWorks

Comment: Заинтересовать можно если самому интересно. Если материал интересен. И если это изначально интересно самому человеку и соответствует его реализации. Я не ставлю задачу заинтересовать. Моя задача это помочь развиться и повысить осознанность а так же раскрыться тем чей путь - разработка.

Answer (score 1):

Что там по поводу .Net 5 - говорят много крутых фишек для микросервисов и не только. Имеет смысл засматриваться на это обновление. Например, для пет-проектов. Или для бизнеса. Я думаю такой вопрос тоже можно наложить на тему.

Answer (score 1):

Всех благодарю за участие!
К сожалению, я не видел чат трансляции и не смог во время эфира ответить на вопросы, поэтому отвечу здесь.

> Использую ли я методы о работе и строении мозга в своей работе.

Я профессионально более 10 лет занимаюсь изучением работы физиологии человека, включая мозг и нервную систему. Кроме того, у меня есть мои авторские наработки и знания, которых вообще нет нигде (80% я использую именно свои авторские методы и знания).
Эти знания я использую при обучении учеников и в корпоративном консалтинге.

Область моих методов:

- Эффективное обучение.
- Развитие личностных качеств, необходимых для развития программиста-разработчика.

Про меня и мои методы можно более подробно почитать на моём сайте
https://okeanij.ru
и обсудить в группе Telegram https://t.me/developer_school

Answer (score 1):

Сегодня  прислали изображения. Не могу удержаться что бы не выложить сюда.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хорошее )))) но это в чат наверное лучше)