# Давайте оживим наши соцсети

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, вехи, вконтакте

Да, они у нас есть:

- [ВКонтакте](https://vk.com/stackoverflow)
- [Twitter](https://twitter.com/rustackoverflow/)
- [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/@ruru2659)

Есть [предыстория создания](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4759/339283). И мы даже проводили [выборы модераторов группы ВКонтакте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6590/339283). Напомню, что избрали тогда [@Suvitruf](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf-andrei-apanasik). Но время идёт. И сейчас все соцсети полностью заброшены. Последние посты в Twitter датируются 2018, а ВКонтакте — 2020.

---

Цель группы ВКонтакте в то время была сформулирована так:

> Привлечь внимание людей, которые все еще используют старые
> phpBB-форумы

Но мне кажется, что эта цель устарела. На мой взгляд, гораздо важнее, что группа даёт нам возможность публиковать *другой* контент. Мы можем отойти от модели *вопрос-ответ* и публиковать то, что нам просто нравится.

Давайте делать это **для себя**. Потому что мы люди, и у нас есть крутые интересные новости, а не только ответы на вопросы:

- [Подкасты с нашими участниками](https://vk.com/wall-33558403_274)
- [Статьи наших участников на Хабр](https://vk.com/wall-33558403_266)
- [Наши очные встречи](https://vk.com/wall-33558403_246)
- [Наш видеочат](https://vk.com/wall-33558403_183)
- [Приглашения на митапы от наших участников](https://vk.com/wall-33558403_153)
- [Собственно, митапы с нашими участниками](https://vk.com/wall-33558403_177)

Дополнительно:

- [Интересные вопросы](https://vk.com/wall-33558403_156)
- [Переводы блога SO](https://vk.com/wall-33558403_173)
- [Наши Мета-конкурсы](https://vk.com/wall-33558403_170)
- [Сезонные ивенты](https://vk.com/wall-33558403_184)
- [Мемы](https://vk.com/wall-33558403_178)

Предлагаю возродить практику ведения соцсетей. И начать это с выбора людей, готовых взять на себя формальную часть этой работы. Напомню, что предложить публикацию может **любой**. Это наша группа. И лично мне было бы очень интересно посмотреть на всех вас с другой стороны.

Comment: Не получилось тут стать модератором, решили там стать модератором? :)

Comment: @nomnoms, здорово придумали. странно, что ни минусуют...я то впринципе тоже самое и искала. два раза свой вопрос меняла...ну да не суть. Вы эту идею хорошо предложили. скопление программистов. и если такое будет, те кто за кордоном смогут родную речь практиковать и обмениваться опытом тоже здорово. в соцсетях можно и картинку попостить и пошутить(и даже рядом две картинки поставить тоже можноыыыыы). и вопрос спросить. да и вообще это изи и найс. я **ЗА** ваше решение. лайк, подписка...

Comment: А вы уверены, что тут нужны люди, которые сидят в соцсетях?

Comment: @avp В первую очередь тут нужны люди, которые тут уже есть. Оживим соцсети, и я буду рад пригласить вас посмотреть на жизнь наших участников с другой стороны

Comment: @nomnoms12, *`"... посмотреть на жизнь наших участников ..."`* -- неужели они смогут увлекательно описывать свои когнитивные процессы? Тогда вряд ли у них останется время на собственно программирование. И в чем тогда будет их ценность тут?

Comment: @avp Это разные виды деятельности, некорректно их сравнивать. Мне интересно не только отвечать на вопросы в рамках ruSO. И судя по нашим прошлым постам, я не один такой

Comment: @nomnoms12, т.е. вместо того, чтобы изменить ruSO так, чтобы он стал опять нам интересен, вы предлагаете перенести активность  в социальные сети (и пусть этот сайтик горит синим огнем)?

Comment: @avp ruSO отвечает декларируемым целям. Интересность и ламповые посиделки топ 40 участников ему нужны настолько-же, насколько и Википедии или Авито, например ))

Comment: @Kromster, если ruSO хочет не загнивать, а развиваться (в свете новых (ChatGPT и т.п.) обстоятельств), то ему желательно пересмотреть свои цели

Comment: @avp давайте срочно напишем им письмо, а то они не знают! ) *SO застрял во времени лет 10 назад как.

Comment: @Kromster, не думаю, что это имеет смысл. Нужно просто делать так, как нам удобней (вплоть до полной самостоятельности)

Comment: *Привлечь внимание людей, которые все еще используют старые phpBB-форумы* ??? SO - это не форум даже близко. Тут даже продолжительный диалог в комментариях - и то неформат.

Comment: А где Телеграм? :) А по делу...
Даже тут достаточно зашумлено, а уж в соцсетях?... Если без комментирования/обсуждения, то это просто дубль., зачем? Если "с трепом", грубо говоря — то будет столько шума, что пользы будет мало. Словом, смысла не вижу никакого, не присоединялся (хотя раз-другой посмотрел, что там) и не планирую.

Comment: @avp: Если лошадь сдохла, надо слезать.

Comment: @VladD, привет! Наверное вы правы, но как-то прикипел я к ней, все жду чего-то несбыточного ...

Comment: @avp У меня была долго ломка, помню. Несбыточного не дождался, переболел.

Comment: @VladD, это хорошо. Сейчас где обитаете?

Comment: @avp: Всё там же, в Мюнхене, наконец-то повысили до архитектора (с начала мая).

Comment: @avp А вы не думали перебираться в наши Пенаты? У нас тут embedded в почёте, потому что автомобильная индустрия.

Comment: @avp: Хотя вам, кажется, embedded не заходил. Вот у меня сейчас проект с embedded, нативная часть бежит под QNX и на ней вполне нормальный gcc с C++17.

Comment: @VladD, перебираться я уже не буду (все же, в 64 это поздно, да и что там моя жена будет делать?), а работаю как раз близко к embedded, точнее в разработке чипов (в Baikal Electronics (нас даже можно найти в вике)). Успехов вам во всем.

Comment: @avp: Про Байкал слыхал, они у нас не распространены по понятным причинам, но проект суперинтересный, так что и вам успехов тоже и чтобы было много интересных задач!

Answer (score 6):

- Социальные сети являются частью сообщества
- Аккаунты социальных сетей SO должны быть достоянием сообщества, а не конкретного участника или CM (это не отменяет наличия ответственных за социальные сети)
- Как следствие, профили в соц.медиа не должны быть заложниками конкретных участников
- Если мы перешли на полное самоуправление, то логично было бы самим принимать решения по поводу социальных сетей

Поначалу мне казалось, что наши соцсети не очень популярны, поскольку я помню что в моменте на трансляциях в Ютубе было по 13 зрителей онлайн и мне показалась данная идея нежизнеспособной.
Но сейчас я проверил и увидел, что вконтакте и в Ютубе записи имеют по полтысячи просмотров.
В целом это приемлемые показатели.

Мое мнение: если у кого-то есть силы и желание вести наши социальные сети, то нужно дать такую возможность.

Comment: *"Аккаунты социальных сетей SO должны быть достоянием сообщества, а не конкретного участника или CM"* - общее - значит ничье. *"Если мы перешли на полное самоуправление"* - а мы разве перешли?

Comment: @Kromster, во всяком случае  это декларировал КМ. Это не значит, что у нас нет проблем с воплощением этой идеи

Comment: Касательно достояния. Это не отменяет того, что должны быть лица ответственные за данные социальные сети

Comment: Мне кстати очень понравилось участвовать в [беседе с Николасом и Дмитрием Поляниным](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10955/337980)- и вроде зрителям было небезынтересно. Так что я бы сказал, что идея достаточно жизнеспособная, если 500-600 просмотров считать успехом. Я считаю.

Comment: @AntonMenshov да, согласен

Comment: Странно, но в YT из имеющихся 10 выпусков видео чата, максимальное кол-во просмотров 343. Не дотягивает до "полтысячи".

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, здесь профейлил. В VK там точно по полтысячи было. Относительно YouTube я смотрел на общее кол-во просмотров - 12 230 просмотров и на кол-во видео (12), но я не учел, что подавляющее большинство из них это видео с механиками я недосмотрел... Так то я изначально писал, что трансляции не собирают...просто не туда посмотрел

Answer (score 3):

*"Давайте оживим **наши** .."*. Как мне кажется здесь **в корне неверное понимание ситуации**.

- SO это частная коммерческая компания, на мощностях которой работает ruSO. Они задают правила и они отвечают за действия (в т.ч. перед РКН, например).
- Делать без согласования якобы-официальные представительства - верный путь получить CnD (cease and desist) или TDN (take down notice). У Николаса эти согласования вероятно были (кстати стоит спросить его).

Чтобы было понятнее, возьмите например Википедию, Хабр, Пикабу, Авито. Представьте что вы (просто участник) хотите сделать их представительства в ВК, Твиттере, на Ютубе. Думаю уже понятно что это значит и влечет? ))

---

Делать фан-клубы ruSO - на здоровье. Просто маркируйте соответственно и делайте кто хотите и что хотите (опять же с учетом потенциального CnD), у кого на это есть силы время и желание. SOпротивление вот было какое-то время популярно ..

Другой вопрос - зачем это вообще нужно. Тут уж кто возьмется, тот идею и придумает.. Но как компания отреагирует на то, что вы хотите "сесть ей на хвост" и получить часть её репутации для раскрутки своего "стартапа" - сложно сказать.

---

Да, неприятно это знать, но это сбережет вас от разочарования через год, когда окажется, что "BeNice для всех", "CnD надо выполнять", "SO решила иначе и надо мигрировать", и т.п. и т.д.

Comment: Но я же ничего нового не придумываю. Соцсети уже есть. Их просто бросили

Comment: @nomnoms12 Я просто обрисовал вам положение вещей. То что на ВК может быть заброшенная полу-офоциальная группа Авито, которую кто-то хотел бы реанимировать, никак не означает, что это не закончится фиаско. Сделайте лучше предварительное исследование, в каком положении находятся соцсети enSO и десятка других разделов SE (что там на фейсбуке enSO или в реддите SuperUser). А дальше, подумайте, хотите ли вы делать что-то бесплатное для коммерческой компании без ее нужды в этом или все же что-то свое, что вы сможете потом конвертировать в нечто большее.

Comment: Мне кажется, тебе кто минусуют, не понимают полностью смысл послания :) Проблем может быть уйма. SO спокойно может ввести правила оформления публикаций. Заставлять писать именно их теги. Бан в том же ВК может привести к бану на SO или ruSO. Реклама, которую мы обязаны будем постить. Да они могут впринципе наложить ограничения на темы, которые можно там опубликовать. Бан может прилететь за безобидную расистскую шутку, которая весело принимается русским обществом, но не SO. Даже если мы всё же добьёмся своего, из-за правок и т.д. это может стать очень скучной затеей, а не тем что мы представляли

Comment: И это лишь первые проблемы, которые мне приходят в голову. Всё может обернуться куда серьезней, если на SO начнётся истерия из-за всего этого. Я не знаю щас эти страницы в русских соцсетях указаны юридически где-то у них или нет. Они могут не захотеть впринципе всем этим связываться. Учитывая настрой в России - всё делать на своих продуктах, может потом выйти боком. Потому это всё очень тщательно стоит обсудить с руководителями

Comment: @EzioMercer Сейчас никаких из озвученных вами проблем нет. Узнать отношение администрации к соцсетям, конечно, стоит. Но ради этого я и создал пост, разве нет?

Comment: @nomnoms12 постом(!) на иностранном языке(!) вы ничего у администрации не узнаете, боги с вами! )) А касательно мероприятия  - подумайте дважды, стоит ли лить воду на чужую мельницу )

Comment: @nomnoms12 На данный момент нет этих проблем, вы правы) Но в вашем вопросе из-за предложения "начать это с выбора людей, готовых взять на себя формальную часть этой работы" может показаться многим, что всё уже готово, осталось только выбрать представителей и всё, можно постить посты. Или вот это может вводить в заблуждение "Это наша группа", она не наша, она SO, была и будет. И правила могут менять как им будет угодно. Ваш вопрос просто как будто опережает своё время - это то почему я написал комментарии выше, чтобы немного сбавить обороты :)

Comment: @Зонтик Вы хотите из нашей бедной меты сделать место для черновиков постов во всех соц сетях? Я точно был бы против такой идеи :) И по-моему такие вопросы явно будут нарушать правила вопросов Меты...

Answer (score 2):

*Наши* звучит хорошо.
Но формат вопрос-ответ, конечно же, не приживётся.

Приживётся что-то вроде [вастрика](https://t.me/vas3k_channel). Но в одиночестве такое вести большой труд, по крайней мере если делать публикации чаще чем в упомянутом клубе, да и там есть коллаб с авторами на VC.

Но, т.к. мы сообщество, довольно интересное сообщество, можно создавать темы для публикации на meta, собирать в ответах мнения, возможно даже проводить интервью на темы, затем всё это компилировать в статью / влог в соц. сетях. Во-первых, компиляция менее трудозатратна, во-вторых, будет отражать плюрализм мнений или какое-то общее мнение, чем, собственно, SO и интересен.

Взять, хотя бы, ветку про [chatGPT](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12247/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-gpt-%D0%B8-chatgpt-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0/12249), пока большинство изучало что это за монстр, мы уже столкнулись с проблемой и хорошо её изучили, так сказать, на передовой.

Answer (score 0):

*Ответ устарел, после правок в вопросе (оставил просто для истории)*

Как мне кажется эта идея была бы хороша, если люди не знали о существовании ruSO. Даже в самой предыстории говорится:

> Основная цель публичной страницы – привлечь внимание людей, которые все еще используют старые phpBB-форумы

Сейчас почти любой запрос про программирование (на русском) ведёт на ruSO. И учитывая сколько людей впринципе тут было, я предполагаю, что в рунете наш сайт довольно популярен. Потому ввести соцсети именно с целью привлечения внимания не вижу смысла

Можно придумать что-то развлекательное, чтобы весело провести время всем

Comment: "Почти любой запрос про программирование (на русском) ведёт на ruSO" — очень смелое заявление. Почти — это сколько?

Comment: @nomnoms12 Если отвечать математически, то почти (в данном контексте) означает, что при бесконечных запросах, доля ответов в первых строках поисковиков не из ruSO стремится к нулю :) Да, согласен, возможно утверждение статистически неверное, но за столько лет запросов на русском языке про программирование, я очень редко не встречал ответы из ruSO. Я написал ответ из своего личного опыта

Comment: Несмотря на то, что основной целью Николай выделил "привлечение внимания людей с форумов", эта цель, очевидно, не единственная. И, возможно, уже не основная

Comment: @nomnoms12 Я был бы рад, если бы (лучше всего в вопросе) изложили свои мысли по поводу цели(ей), того зачем это ещё нужно кроме как привлечение людей к нам на сайт. Тогда возможно я увижу больше смысла в этом и буду на вашей стороне

Comment: Обновил вопрос; добавил посты, которые мне понравились. Если чего-то не видели, то рад показать :)