# Почему вопрос, набравший много голосов ЗА, не попал в секцию "Обсуждаемое на Мете"?

Tags: поддержка, мета, обсуждаемое-на-мете

Есть такой довольно интересный вопрос: [Давайте оживим наши соцсети](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12610/%d0%94%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8)

У этого вопроса (на данный момент) 9 голосов ЗА и 1 голос ПРОТИВ, но не смотря на его популярность, я его ни разу так и не увидел в секции "Обсуждаемое на мете". А вопросы с намного меньшим количеством голосов ЗА попадали туда без проблем.

Кто знает, объясните пожалуйста, каким критериям (помимо большого количества голосов ЗА) должен соответствовать вопрос на Мете, чтобы попасть в "Обсуждаемое на Мете"?

Comment: Добавил метку [meta-tag:обсуждение] к упомянутому вопросу. Пусть покрутится.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ А точно так можно?) По-моему нужно изначально создать вопрос с такой меткой

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Вопрос отпал - https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfYX6.png :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На нем нет метки [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5). Кроме того, 4 слота в "Обсуждаемом на Мете" уже заняты.

Критерии попадания в этот блок: [What criteria are used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin sidebar block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130621/243121)

Comment: А, я думал "предложения" тоже туда должны попадать. На счёт "4 слота уже заняты" - я уже который день наблюдаю как там несколько вопросов, то показываются то нет. И я так понял, что они там стоят в очереди и каждому уделяется +- одинаковое внимание

Comment: @EzioMercer по слотам, емнип, есть ротация, если их больше требуется.